# How do I integrate NTLM authentication with Perl's SOAP::Lite module?

Tags: perl, soap, ntlm

This Perl code works with Anonymous access to an ASP.NET web service, but when integrated security is turned on, the service returns 401 errors. I think I need to use the NTLM module in conjunction with SOAP::Lite, but it's not clear how to do so. How can these components be integrated?

```
use SOAP::Lite;
use strict;

my $proxy = "http://localhost:28606/WebService.asmx";

my $method_name = "HelloWorld";
my $uri = "http://tempuri.org/";
my $methodAction = $uri . $method_name;

my $soap = SOAP::Lite
    ->uri( $uri )
    ->proxy( $proxy )
    ->on_action(sub{ $methodAction; });

my $method = SOAP::Data->name($method_name)->attr({xmlns=>$uri});
my $result = $soap->call($method);

print $result->result();
```

Comment: What exactly is "integrated security"?

Answer (score 2):

You can get SOAP::Lite to print some debugging output if you do:

```
use SOAP::Lite +trace;
```

instead of

```
use SOAP::Lite;
```

EDIT:

OK, I think I get it now. Turning on the integrated security feature makes IIS require NTLM authentication. There's a [thread over at perlmonks.org](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=719995) that seems to reveal the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late, but I just faced the same problem. Try this:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use LWP::Debug;
use SOAP::Lite on_action => sub { "$_[0]$_[1]"; };
import SOAP::Data 'name', 'value';
our $sp_endpoint = 'http://sp.example.com/sites/mysite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx';
our $sp_domain = 'sp.example.com:80';
our $sp_username = 'DOMAIN\username';
our $sp_password = 'xyz';

if ($debug) {
    LWP::Debug::level('+');
    SOAP::Lite->import(+trace => 'all');
}

my @ua_args = (keep_alive => 1);
my @credentials = ($sp_domain, "", $sp_usernam, $sp_password);
my $schema_ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(@ua_args);
$schema_ua->credentials(@credentials);
$soap = SOAP::Lite->proxy($sp_endpoint, @ua_args, credentials => \@credentials);
$soap->schema->useragent($schema_ua);
$soap->uri("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/");
```